# How do I get an evaluation function from this Alpha Beta Pruning exercise?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning, pruning

I have an alpha beta pruning exercise that states the following (dots and boxes):

Next, a strategy game is described:

- Starting with an empty grid of dots, players (A and B) take turns, adding a single horizontal or vertical line between two unjoined adjacent dots.
- A player who completes the fourth side of a 1×1 box earns one point and takes another turn.
- The game ends when no more lines can be placed. The winner of the game is the player with the most
  points.

The question is:

How do I Define an ​evaluation function​ to be used by the algorithm? Assume that ​MAX ​plays with color ​player A

[image]

A guiding photo

Comment: You can check my suggestion

Comment: The simplest evaluation function is just the score for boxes already created. In the example, the score for `start` to `7B` would be 0. At `8A` it's 1, and at `9B` it's -2.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is to have the coordinates `x,y` of each point `( (0,0) (0,1) (0,2) ; (1,0) (1,1) (1,2) ; (2,0) (2,1) (2,2) )`

Each player will have a **list of the points that he linked** with a bar , then the evaluation will be in that way , you will see all the linked points , **`for each point with a coordinates (a,b) you will see if there is 3 points with following conditions { (a,b) (a,b+1) (a+1,b) (a+1,b+1) }`** , if yes then a cube is created

Example :

The player MAX , created a link between (0,0) and (0,1) , between (0,0) and (1,0) , between (1,0) and (1,1) and between (0,1) and (1,1 ) , then all these points will be added to his list

Now let's take one point (0,0) and make the evaluation , for all elements in the list , if there exist 3 elements which satisfies the 3 conditions `{ (a,b+1) (a+1,b) (a+1,b+1) }` then we can say that there is a created cube